# How can my child component update my parent component in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My parent component is a list of tabs. Clicking on tab leads me to Child #1 or Child #2. I can also route to Child #1 or Child #2 by URL. In this case, I check the path to know which tab to select programatically.

My problem comes when I redirect from one child to another. My parent is oblivious to the fact that a change has occurred - none of the initializing functions in that component get called, since it is already rendered. Therefore the tab that was originally selected (Child #1) - remains selected even though I am now viewing Child #2.

The tab that is selected is being stored in the parent's state - is there any way for me to update the parent's state from the child component?

Comment: sounds like you need some family counseling ;)

Comment: It would seem that you should move your state to the parent component so that it can be aware of any state changes but if you can't do that, then you can try forcing an update of the parent component from the child component via `forceUpdate([function callback])` https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#forceupdate

Comment: The state in question is in the parent component, but I'm not sure how to modify that state from the child component.  I'd like to avoid using `forceUpdate` for now as I've yet to have to use it.

Comment: just pass a function (as a prop) that can modify the state from parent to child.

Comment: code please :), would be helpfull

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass a function down to the child(ren) from the parent that modifies the state accordingly. A very simple version could be something like:

```
class Parent {
  setActive(activeId) {
    this.setState({active: activeId});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Child setActive={this.setActive}/>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I wasn't aware I could pass down functions through prop.